# A better way to search an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, array-algorithms

Often times I'll find myself having to access a particular object from an object or array of objects that are indexed by arbitrary indices, but the object I need is one who's key matches a particular value.

For example:

```
var cars = [
    { id:23, make:'honda', color: 'green' },
    { id:36, make:'acura', color:'silver' },
    { id:18, make:'ford', color:'blue' },
    { id:62, make:'ford', color:'green' }, 
];
```

Suppose I need one of these entries and I know this entry unique; the one where id=18, for instance.

Right now, Im doing this in the following way:

```
function select(key,val,arr){

    for(var i in arr){
        if(arr[i][key]==val) return(arr[i]);
    }
    return(null); // object not present in arr
}


var id = 18;
var car = select('id', id, cars);

// car = { id:18, make:'ford', color:'blue' }
```

But this seems cumbersome and scales poorly as it varies in performance. A value from a large dataset may be returned very quickly, if its towards the beginning of the array or, at worst, will take as many iterations as there are entries. 
This also seems very wasteful if the value doesn't exist at all, since you've just iterated over all the objects just to come up with a null result.

Is there a more elegant way of searching an array or object for a value when the search criteria is not the same parameter as the subject's keys?

Comment: do not use `for ... in` on an `array`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Array.prototype.map()` to create a shadow array, which will help you search more fast, or furthermore you can create an `index` object like below, it will directly return the index you need.

```
var cars = [
    { id:23, make:'honda', color: 'green' },
    { id:36, make:'acura', color:'silver' },
    { id:18, make:'ford', color:'blue' },
    { id:62, make:'ford', color:'green' }, 
];
let cars_s = cars.map(function(x) {
    return x.id;
});
let i = cars_s.indexOf(18);
console.log(i); // 2
console.log(cars[i]); // { id:18, make:'ford', color:'blue' }

let index = {};
for (let i = 0; i < cars_s.length; i++) {
    index[cars_s[i]] = i;
}
console.log(index[18]); // 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an object whose keys are the property you want to be able to search by:

```
var cars_by_id = {};
cars.forEach(c => cars_by_id[c.id] = c);
```

Now you can use `cars_by_id[id]` to get the car you want.

Whenever you push onto `cars`, you'll also need to add to `cars_by_id`. You might want to define a class that automates this.

Comment: You beat me by 2 seconds. :)

Comment: but doesnt this just transfer the processing task into another form? obviously iterating over the entire object with `cars.forEach(c => cars_by_id[c.id] = c);` once is much better than having to do it over and over when searching, but this can still become a significant performance load if the subject array count is in the millions

Comment: It depends on how often you need to search for things. If you hide it in a class, you never need to do that loop, you just keep the object and array in sync from the time you create them.

Answer (score 1):

Construct an object where each key is the id of a car object and the value is the car object itself:

```
var cars = {
    23: { id:23, make:'honda', color: 'green' },
    36: { id:36, make:'acura', color:'silver' },
    18: { id:18, make:'ford', color:'blue' },
    62: { id:62, make:'ford', color:'green' }, 
};
```

This will be much quicker to access like this:

```
console.log(cars[18].make);
```

Comment: this would be ideal, but sometimes infeasible since the data may be coming of sources out of my control. even in a simple case, MySQL db calls tend not return data in this format, and re-formatting when its received just passes the computing dilemma up the task chain